# Supremum of an uncountable collection of functions and compact convergence

Tags: probability, measure-theory, uniform-convergence

Let $\Omega = C(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{A}$ on $\Omega$ is defined to be the smallest $\sigma$-field such that the coordinate map $\Phi_t: \omega \mapsto \omega(t)$ is measurable for all $t \ge 0$.

Now I want to show that the function $\Phi: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$
$$ \Phi = \sup_{t\le s} \Phi_t$$
is measurable.

One way is to observe that
$$\Phi(\omega) = \sup_{t\le s} \Phi_t(\omega) = \sup_{t\le s}\omega(t) = \sup_{t\le s \ \text{and } t \in \mathbb{Q}} \omega(t)$$
by the continuity of $\omega$. Hence, as a supremum of a countable collection of measurable functions, $\Phi$ is measurable.

I was told that another way is to use the following fact:

> The $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{A}$ coincides with the Borel $\sigma$-field when $\Omega$ is
> endowed with the topology of compact convergence (i.e., uniform convergence on every compact set).

But I can't see how this fact can be used to prove the measurability of $\Phi$.

Comment: $\Phi$ is continuous, hence Borel measurable, for the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.

Comment: @geetha290krm Oh yeah that's right. Thanks a lot!